# any method like onshow() for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a div that is shown or hidden dynamically. I want some function to execute when the div is shown for the first time. Let me know how to do that.

```
<div id="firstDiv"></div>
<div id="secondDiv"></div>
```

so when `$('#secondDiv").show();`
I want to perform some function.

How I can do that?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432111/how-to-write-onshow-event-using-javascript-jquery/6244083#6244083

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can provide a callback function to the `show` function, which will be executed upon completion of `show`:

```
$("#secondDiv").show(function() { 
    //Do something 
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, this will behave as an animation. If you want `show` to behave as normal (i.e. the element appears instantly with no animation) you need to supply a duration parameter of 0 to the `show` function. The difference is demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/bkgcy/).

Comment: worth mentioning that `$("#secondDiv").show([callback])` is essentially calling an animate effect equivalent to `$("#secondDiv").show(400, [callback])` where `400` is the default duration in milliseconds for the animation.  Maybe consider `0` for the animation duration `$("#secondDiv").show(0, [callback])`, unless you are looking to keep an animation effect.

Comment: Yes, very good point. I've updated the answer to mention that, and provided a link to a demonstration of the difference.

Comment: BTW how do i add animation to that? i have Jquery UI plugin too.

Comment: It depends how you want to animate it. Have a look at the `animate` function to animate a custom set of CSS properties. To have it slide down/up, look at `slideUp` and `slideDown`. To fade, look at `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.